# Count characters in two specific lines in all files and printing the sum with corresponding filename

Tags: linux, awk, sed, perl

Following is the case: there are multiple *.txt files each containing below lines with different values of `var` or `lab`.

For example:

`abc.txt`:

```
var^ABCDEFG
lab^ABCDEFGH
```

`def.txt`:

```
var^ABCDEFGHI
lab^ABCDEFGHIJ
```

I need a command or script which will print sum of number of characters in (`var^` or `lab^`) for each .txt file.
Sample output:

```
abc.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 15.        (counting character after the caret ^ sign)
def.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 19.
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! Should characters after `var^` and `lab^` only be counted if those two strings appear in the line beginning? Can you share your attempts or research to try to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Specifically, do _all_ lines begin with `var^` or `lab^`? Are there empty lines? Are there more patterns where the number of following characters should be considered?

Comment: There are other lines in the text file which will always begin with <word>^ <text>.

Comment: var^ or lab^ can be anywhere in the text files and will appear only at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding @steeldriver's answer to other `awk` implementations without `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` makes it a bit messier, but portable:

```
awk -F'^' 'FNR==1{if (NR>FNR) printf("%s : Total characters in (Var) and (Lab) are %d\n",lastfile,sum); sum=0; lastfile=FILENAME} \
 NF==2 && ($1=="var" || $1=="lab") {sum+=length($2)} \
 END{printf "%s: Total characters in (Var) and (Lab) are %d\n", FILENAME, sum}' abc.txt def.txt
```

To explain:

- At beginning of file, (i.e. `FNR`, the per-file-line counter, is 1), we store the filename in a temporary variable `lastfile` and set the counter variable to 0.
- If this is not the first file (i.e. `NR`, the global line-counter, is larger than `FNR`), we output the statistics from the previous file.
- Since this rule would not catch the last file on `awk`'s argument list, we have to replicate the logic also in the global `END` block.

Comment: @AdmionBee  I executed the code above and there is message awk:                                                                                                                       ^ backslash not last character on line

Comment: it worked :). Thanks for your time and quick help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
for file in *.txt; do \
  echo -n "$file: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are "; 
  cut -d "^" -f 2 < $file | tr -d '\n' | wc -c;
done
```

Output:

```
abc.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 15                                                                       
def.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 15
```

Comment: Above code assumes that there are only two lines in each file starting with VAR and LAB.  There are other lines in the text file which will always begin with <word>^ <text>.   var^ or lab^ can be anywhere in the text files and will appear only at the beginning of the line

Comment: You should include this information in the question then!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this with GNU awk:

```
gawk -F^ '
  BEGINFILE{count=0} 
  $1 == "var" || $1 == "lab" {count += length($2)} 
  ENDFILE{printf("%s: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are %d\n", FILENAME, count)}
' ???.txt
abc.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 15
def.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
co=0
k=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
t=re.compile(r'var\^|lab\^')
for i in k:
    m=re.sub(t,"",i)
    co=co+len(m.strip())
print "{0}: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are {1}".format(sys.argv[1],co)



$ python test.py abc.txt 
abc.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 15


$ python test.py def.txt
def.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 19
```

Awk method

```
    #!/bin/bash
    awk -F "var|lab" 'BEGIN{sum=0}{gsub(/\^/,"",$2)}{sum=sum+length($2)}END{print FILENAME ": Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are "sum}' $1


 sh test.sh abc.txt 
abc.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 15


sh tes.sh def.txt 
def.txt: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are 19
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `grep` and `wc`:

```
for i in *.txt; do
  printf '%s: Total Characters in (Var and Lab) are %d.\n'\
    "$i"\
    "$(( $(grep -E '^(var|lab)' "$i" | wc -c) - 10 ))"
done
```